# VS Code python terminal is keep printing "Found" when it should ask the user for an input

Tags: python, sql, cs50

I am taking cs50 class. Currently on Week 7.

Prior to this coding, python was working perfectly fine.
Now, I am using SQL command within python file on VS Code.
cs50 module is working fine through venv.

When I execute python file, I should be asked "Title: " so that I can type any titles to see the outcome.
I should be getting an output of the counter, which tracks the number of occurrence of the title from user input.

```
import csv
from cs50 import SQL


db = SQL("C:\\Users\\wf user\\Desktop\\CODING\\CS50\\shows.db")

title = input("Title: ").strip()

#uses SQL command to return the number of occurrence of the title the user typed.
rows = db.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) AS counter FROM shows WHERE title LIKE ?", title) #? is for title. 
    #db.execute always returns a list of rows even if it's just one row.

#setting row to the keyword which is is rows[0]. the actual value is in rows[1]
row = rows[0]

#passing the key called counter will print out the value that is in rows[1]
print(row["counter"])
```

[I have shows.db in the path.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yf8qX.png)

But the output is printing "Found". It's not even asking for a Title to input.

> PS C:\Users\wf user\Desktop\CODING\CS50> python favoritesS.py
>
> > Found

I am expecting the program to ask me "Title: " for me, but instead it's print "Found"

In cs50, the professor encountered the same problem when he was coding phonebook.py, but the way he solved the problem was he put the python file into a separate folder called "tmp"

I tried the same way but then I was given a long error message

> ```
> PS C:\Users\wf user\Desktop\CODING\CS50> cd tmp
> PS C:\Users\wf user\Desktop\CODING\CS50\tmp> python favoritesS.py
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\wf user\Desktop\CODING\CS50\tmp\favoritesS.py", line 5, in <module>
> db = SQL("C:\\Users\\wf user\\Desktop\\CODING\\CS50\\shows.db")
>
> File "C:\Users\wf user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cs50\sql.py", line 74, in __init__
> self._engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url, **kwargs).execution_options(autocommit=False, isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT")
>
> File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
> File "C:\Users\wf user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py", line 309, in warned
> return fn(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\wf user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 518, in create_engine
> u = _url.make_url(url)
>
> File "C:\Users\wf user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py", line 732, in make_url
> return _parse_url(name_or_url)
>
> File "C:\Users\wf user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py", line 793, in _parse_url
> raise exc.ArgumentError(
> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse SQLAlchemy URL from string 'C:\Users\wf user\Desktop\CODING\CS50\shows.db'
> ```

[Here is the proof that the code I posted is the same code I am working on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK09C.png)

[I use Start Debugging under Run menu on VSCode and it's working! But not when I don't use debugging.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZ3U6.png)

Comment: To explain the first problem, you have a file named `favoritesS.py` in both the CS50 directory and in the CS50/tmp directory.  The one in the CS50 directory does _not_ have an `input()` statement, so it does not ask for input.

Comment: To explain the second problem, `shows.db` does not exist in the CS50/tmp directory.  Also according to the documentation, the SQL string should look like `sqlite:///file.db` for local files.

Comment: print rows instead and show the reslt

Comment: Does it look  suspicious to anyone else that this file name `C:\\Users\\wf user\\Desktop\\CODING\\CS50\\shows.db` contains a space?

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus It's somewhat unusual for directories/filenames to have spaces, but it's not an error.

Comment: @JohnGordon I got the FOUND problem even before I created tmp folder to put the duplicated favoritesS.py into the folder. Now I got rid of tmp folder. I changed the db statement to **db = SQL("sqlite:///shows.db")** I have the same **title = input("Title: ").strip()** in favoritesS.py, so I believe when I run the code, it should ask me for an input but it's still printing ***Found***.

Comment: If the code is not asking you for input, then my only explanation is that you have shown us the wrong code, and there actually _isn't_ an `input()` statement in the program you are running.

Comment: @JohnGordon David J. Malan, who is the professor in cs50 also encountered the same problem but he couldn't fix it other than creating TMP folder and moved the file, then it started working. His error was exactly same as mine. I am currently working on favoritesS.py and the code I posted is what I am working on currently. I will post the picture to prove that I am working on the code that I posted.

Comment: Add some random `print()` statements to the top of the file and see if that output appears.

Comment: I tried RUN and Debug, and it's working perfectly. I don't know what's going on. It only works when I start debug. When I use terminal command **python favoritesS.py** it doesn't work but just print out Found.

Comment: What is "RUN and Debug"?  Are you using an IDE?

Comment: This is a long shot, but try this code and show us the output: `import os; print(os.listdir())`  The filenames from that screenshot might be misleading.

Comment: @JohnGordon I posted another picture of the way I used debugging and how it's working perfectly. It's printing out a long blue lines on the terminal.

Comment: @JohnGordon It prints out the following when I run **import os; print(os.listdir())** ['agree.py', 'argv.py', 'exit.py', 'favorites.csv', 'favorites.sql', 'favorites0.py', 'favorites1.py', 'favorites2.py', 'favoritesD.py', 'favoritesO.py', 'favoritesRE.py', 'favoritesS.py', 'favoritesUI.py', 'hello.py', 'hogwarts0.py', 'hogwarts1.py', 'libcs50-11.0.1', 'mario.py', 'meow.py', 'names.py', 'numbers.py', 'parity.py', 'phonebook.py', 'phonebook2.py', 'point.py', 'scores.py', 'shows.db', 'speech.py', 'tmp', 'try.py', 'uppercase.py', 'venv', '__pycache__']

Comment: Well, that file output looks right.  So much for my long shot.

Comment: Did you try adding extra `print()` messages at the top?

Comment: @JohnGordon When I debug, it prints the extra print("It's working") then asks for the input so it's great. Problem is when I do **python favoritesS.py** IT goes back to ***Found*** Seems like Debug and running code are using different routes I guess?

Comment: My only other guess is that the `cs50` package somehow interferes with the standard `input()` function.  Try commenting out that import and the `db = SQL(...)` lines, just to see if that fixes the `input()` call.  (It will crash on the `db.execute` line, because the `db` variable was not declared, but we might learn something.)

Comment: @JohnGordon if it only interferes **input()** why is **print()** not working? And another thing is **favoritesUI.py** which also asks for an input works fine. the print function also works perfectly. It's just this specific python file **favoritesS.py*** is having a problem, and if the code is not the problem, then I wonder what's causing this mysterious error that just prints ***Found***.. I just created a new file with just two lines: **print("It's wroking")** and **title = input("Title: ").strip()** and they are working fine.

Comment: I assume the Found output comes from `print(row["counter"])`.  Try printing `row` also.

Comment: I tried **print(row)** and it still gave ***Found***

Comment: Somehow, `python favoritesS.py` is running different code than you have shown us.  I can't explain why.  If you just type `python` at the prompt, with no filename argument, what happens?

Comment: @JohnGordon It shows ***Python 3.11.1 (tags/v3.11.1:a7a450f, Dec  6 2022, 19:58:39) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information*** I guess this means it's working. Are there anyways to figure out why debug executes the correct file while a simple run executes a different code? It's weird that both execute different codes

Answer (score 1):

Is this the library you are using? https://cs50.readthedocs.io/

It may be that one of your intermediate results is not doing what you think it is.  I would recommend you put `print()` statements at every step of the way to see the values of the intermediate variables.

If you have learned how to use a debugger, that is even better.

Comment: no john gordon is on the right track